# Don' t duck audio volume if notification is inaudible?

Tags: android, notifications, android-audiomanager

The standard way of handling a loss of AudioFocus that can be "ducked" is as follows:

```
OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        if (focusChange == AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {
            // Lower the volume
        } 
    }
};
```

However, if this is implemented as shown you will lower the volume even if the notification is inaudible, such as when DnD mode is turned on in Android 5.0+. There are apparently several different methods for determining if DnD is active: `getAutomaticZenRule()` (wtf?), `getCurrentInterruptionFilter()`, and `getNotificationPolicy()` (which requires special access). None of which are available in < API 23.

Is there a succinct way of telling if the stream requesting AudioFocus that is duck-able is actually audible without muddling through all of the above? It seems Google Play Music handles this case fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        if (focusChange == AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {
             if (!(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION) == 0))
            // Lower the volume
        } 
    }
};
```

does the job.